# How integration tests are performed on your company/job/project?

Tags: testing, process, integration-testing, testimonials, test-plan

I want to improve integration tests methods where I work and I would like to know how this process happens in other places.
Things like:
 - When test plans writing begin
 - Proportion between testers, developers and stuff (entire applications or modifications) to be tested
 - What kind of methods are used for integration testing.

Actually, I test webapps and test plans are managed with Test Link. Bugs found are reported on Bugzilla. I am trying to automate tests with Selenium RC, but I takes some time to write the plans and write the code to execute on Selenium. And time is something that I dont have, because I am testing 3 or more aplications.

Most of my problems are caused by differences between test environment and production environment. But tests are taking too long to begin. If someone finishes a modification today, it will take about 3 weeks for me to begin tests. And the test process queue keeps growing.

It would be really good if anyone suggests something that would improve testing process (like more people testing,etc). But mostly, I would like to hear **how testing process works on other places**.
Thanks.

Comment: lord how I wish I could answer this :)

Comment: Hehe, indeed. Our biggest problem with integration testing is the complete lack of it.

Answer (score 1):

For us the integration test is generally performed by the developer before a commit. Just simple surface test to see that nothing obvious is broken.

Then we deploy the code from trunk on a development server connected to a test database that is a complete copy of the production database and have the users responsible for the new functionality do acceptance test and further integration tests on that server.

We have a concept of "super user" to organize this. Super users are responsible for educating other users in their area of expertise and answering helpdesk questions related to the usage of the system. The super users are also the people who are involved in feature requests and requirement discussions for all features related to their work.

So when a new feature is developed the super user is the one who first validate the design suggestion and than performs the final stages of testing before deployment.

This setup is good because it ensures that domain experts are the ones who validate the system functionality and removes some responsibilities from the IT-department.

The bad thing is that they are not usually very technical or good testers. As users they tend to see the the system for what is is rather than what it could be. The fact that they also have their ordinary functions in the organization as full time employees also means that they are a very limited resource in terms of testing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean integration testing as in checking to see if the parts of the application work together, (for example, getting the database and the website to work together after the DBA and web developer respectively say they're done) And I'll use an example from my current project

- I code generate several configuration files so I can observe the application with certain modules on/off, namely error reporting, authentication, debug mode compilation, with/without SSL.  Development environments are likely to have "friendly error pages" turned off, no authentication, no SSL, etc.
- I also use a build script to create a copy of the application for each variant of the config file
- It is helpful to pedantically reproduce the characteristics of production to staging and development as much as you can-- use virtual machines if you lack the hardware
- I also wrote into the production code bases a few pages that test the sort of things that break when code move from one machine to another, i.e. does the db connection work, do emails send, is the temp folder writable and made that page the home page of the server operator

The key is automating as much as you can.  Frequent integration testing catches issues earlier.

From check in to packaging code for deployment, it takes me 8 minutes of automated work and 1/2 hour of manual clicking for smoke tests.